# Write a python program which generates a matrix:

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Write a python program which generates for given n ∈ N the matrix A^n ∈ R^(2n×2n).
For n = 4 the matrix looks as follows:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxH5u.png)
Entries, which are not shown, should be initialized with 0. Avoid loops! Hint: use np.block and np.fliplr.

```
import numpy as np

n = 4

A = np.block([[1, 2, 0, 0],
          [3, 1, 2, 0],
          [0, 3, 1, 2],
          [0, 0, 3, 1]])

A = np.block([[A, np.zeros((4, 4))],
          [np.zeros((4, 4)), np.fliplr(A)]])

A = np.block([[A, np.zeros((8, 4))],
          [np.zeros((4, 8)), np.flipud(A)]])

print(A)
```

This is what i tried but i get and error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 8
and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: please fix code formatting

Comment: The role of `n` is unclear what would be the output for `n=3` or `n=5`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np

n = 4

A = np.block([[1, 2, 0, 0],
          [3, 1, 2, 0],
          [0, 3, 1, 2],
          [0, 0, 3, 1]])

B = np.block([[A, np.zeros((n, n))],
          [np.zeros((n, n)), np.fliplr(A)]])

C = np.block([[B, np.zeros((2 * n, n))],
          [np.zeros((n, 2 * n)), np.flipud(np.fliplr(B))]])

print(C)
```

Comment: it still doesnt work :(